# Excluding different ranges or data points from a data set

Tags: list-manipulation, datadrop

If I have some list of data, I often want to remove individual points or chunks of data. I usually do this with `Drop[...]` but as far as I can tell, it isn't possible to drop multiple "regions". I often end up using nested drops -- which is a bit clumsy

Is there a better way to more intuitively and most importantly, flexibly select regions of a list to drop or exclude?

Comment: How about `Delete`?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can define your own drop function:

```
MyDrop[list_?ListQ, t : ( _Integer | ( _ ;; _)) ..] := Block[{idx},
   idx = Replace[List[t], x_Integer -> x ;; x, 1];
   idx = Apply[Union, Replace[idx, Span[x_, y_] :> Range[x, y], 1]];
   Delete[list, Map[List, idx]]
   ];
```

Usage example:

```
MyDrop[Range[10], 5, 7 ;; 9, 6 ;; 8]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 10}

Answer (score 1):

*(Note that contrary to the other answers, any valid [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop) syntax is supported)*

How about something like:

```
dropList[expr_, pos__] := With[{indices = Range @ Length @ expr},
    expr[[Complement[indices, Take[indices, #]& /@ Unevaluated[Sequence[pos]]]]]
]
```

For example:

```
dropList[Range[10], 2, 2;;6;;2, -2]
```

> {3, 5, 7, 8}

Since I use [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take) to construct the elements to be deleted, any valid [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop) (or [`Take`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Take)) specification is supported. For example::

```
dropList[Range[20], 2, {4,6}, 9;;UpTo[100];;2]
```

> {3, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20}

Answer (score 0):

```
DropPosition[list_, p_] :=
 Delete[list, List /@ Splice @* Range @@@ Replace[List @@@ p, a_Integer :> {a, a}, 1]]

DropPosition[Range[10], {5, 7 ;; 9, 6 ;; 8}]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 10}

```
DropPosition[CharacterRange["A", "K"], {5, 7 ;; 9, 6 ;; 8}]
```

{"A", "B", "C", "D", "J", "K"}